# c++ T::BrowserWeb is parsed as a non type, but instantiation yields a type

Tags: c++, templates, factory

have class next :

```
class Capabilities{
    public:
        enum Type{BrowserWeb, OsWeb};
        virtual ~Capabilities() = default;
        virtual void printCapabilities()=0;
        static Type type;
}

class CapabilitiesFactory{
    public:
        template < typename T>
        std::unique_ptr<Capabilities> createCapabilities(typename T::Type type){
        std::unique_ptr<Capabilities> caps;
        if( type == T::BrowserWeb) {                //<- error 
            caps = std::make_unique<BrowserWeb>();
        }
        if(caps != nullptr) caps->type = type;
            return caps;
        } 

        template<typename T>
        std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
            auto caps = createCapabilities<T>(T::type);
            return std::unique_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T*>(caps.release()));
        }
};

class BrowserWeb : public Capabilities{
    public:
        static Type type;
        void printCapabilities() override;
}
```

main.cpp

```
auto factory = CapabilitiesFactory();
auto cap = factory.create<BrowserWeb>();
```

in factory .create an error occure in classFactory  if( type == T::BrowserWeb) {   error : dependent-name T::BrowserWEb is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type

thank for youe help

have add if( type == typename T::BrowserWeb) { error Except ( for function-style cast

Comment: using `BrowserWeb` to name different things is confusing. My guess is that if you fix that the error will be trivial to fix

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The code you posted has other errors https://godbolt.org/z/GWjKo88jn

Comment: You have a member with the same name as the class, which can't work. `BrowserWeb::BrowserWeb` refers to the `BrowserWeb` class, not to the inherited`Capabilities::BrowserWeb` member. Deliberate name clashes are a bad idea. Rename one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CapabilitiesFactory{
public:
    template < typename T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> createCapabilities(Capabilities::Type type){
    std::unique_ptr<T> caps;
    if( type == Capabilities::Type::BrowserWeb) {                
        caps = std::make_unique<BrowserWeb>();
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
        auto caps = createCapabilities<T>(T::type);
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T*>(caps.release()));
    }
};
```

in files BrowserWeb.cpp

```
Capabilities::Type BrowserWen::type = Capabilities::Type::BrowserWeb;
```

Thank for comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).